# java. Помогите найти ошибку в цикле

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

```
int[] arrFirst = {1,6};
int[] arrSecond = {4};

public void addition() {
    int[] arr = new int[this.arrFirst.length+this.arrSecond.length];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, m = 0; i != arr.length; i++) {
        if (this.arrFirst[m] < this.arrSecond[j]) {
            arr[i] = this.arrFirst[m];
            if (m != this.arrFirst.length){
                m++;
            }
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        } else {
            arr[i] = this.arrSecond[j];
            if (j < this.arrSecond.length){
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том что у меня падает `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` припроверке `this.arrFirst[m] < this.arrSecond[j]` на третей итерации, хотя `j` которая следит за этим установлена в `if (j != this.arrSecond.length)` и инкрементироваться при достидении долинны массива -1 не должна.

Подскажите где я облажался? Что-то не как не найду(((

Comment: в предыдущем вопросе есть пример кода, если сравнишь со своим, увидишь, что у тебя нет проверок, что в один массив уже весь впихнули

Comment: ну и если у тебя `m` уже равно `length` - то на строчке выше ты получишь исключение, которое и получаешь сейчас :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема была в том, что `j` становилось больше, чем `arrSecond.length`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arrFirst = {1,6, 7, 8};
    int[] arrSecond = {2,4};

    int[] arr = new int[arrFirst.length+arrSecond.length];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, m = 0; i != arr.length ; i++) {
        if(m < arrFirst.length) {
            if (j == arrSecond.length) {
                arr[i] = arrFirst[m];
                m++;
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
                continue;
            }
            if (arrFirst[m] < arrSecond[j]) {
                arr[i] = arrFirst[m];
                if (m != arrFirst.length) {
                    m++;
                }
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            } else {
                arr[i] = arrSecond[j];
                if (j != arrSecond.length) {
                    j++;
                }
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

вывод

```
1
2
4
6
7
8
```

**UPD**

ответ на вопрос из комментария этого ответа

> каким образом j становилось больше, чем arrSecond.length!

1 итерация:

```
i = 0, j = 0, m = 0
```

выполняется условие `if (j == arrSecond.length)` , где `m++`

2 итерация:

```
i = 1, j = 0, m = 1
```

условие не выполняется -> переходим в else, где `j++`

3 итерация:
i = 2, j = 1, m = 1

у тебя j отвечает за второй массив, который имеет 1 элемент, поэтому `arrSecond[j]` вернет тебе `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, потому что ты вышел за пределы массива.

Comment: только вот этот код не сортирует массив по возрастанию

Comment: Да но каким образом j становилось больше, чем arrSecond.length! Вот что не понятно ведь указано что она увеличивается только в случае если if (j != this.arrSecond.length). Нигде в другом месте ее значение не меняется, только используется. Вот что не понятно. То что она становится больше это я и так понял а вот почему??? Вот это я не понимаю...

Comment: @Павел, индексация массива начинается с 0. когда m=length-1, проверка проходит, m увеличивается, на следующем круге - все падает, потому что в массиве не может быть элемента с номером индекса равным длине

Comment: @Павел обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Теперь дошло.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте тут `if (j != this.arrSecond.length)` заменить `!=` на `<`

Comment: Нет к сожалению не сработало.